# Is it possible to Display None using href link?

Tags: html, css, display

```
<a href="example.html">Any text or Image<a>
```

I wanted to add display none using the value of href.

Eg: I just want to add `display: none` to all anchor tags which redirect to `example.html`. All other anchor tags should be still visible.

In other words I just want to hide the links which go to `example.html`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following solution, using a [attribute selector](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors):

```css
a[href="example.html"] {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="example.html">Any text or Image<a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow<a>
```

You can also use `a[href$="example.html"]` if the `href` contains the full url:

```css
a[href$="example.html"] {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="example.html">Any text or Image<a>
<a href="https://example.com/example.html">Any text or Image<a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow<a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Go through by following:-

```css
a[href="example.html"]{display:none !important;}
```

Comment: Why are you using `!important`?

Comment: may b sometime there is class with a tag and having css display:block, than it will not work without imaportant

Answer (score 0):

```
[href="'example.html'"]{display: none;}
```

This will hide all the anchor tags having the value as 'example.html'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to target the desired anchor tag.

```
[href="example.html"] {
  display: none;
}
```